# Spring boot web application won't connect with aws rds postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect my local spring boot application to an aws rds. While I can perfectly connect with pgadmin or from inside IntelliJ it just isn't working inside my spring boot application on localhost. This is my spring boot config:

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.sql.init.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://odyxdb.c56c5slasovs.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/odyxdb
spring.datasource.username=TEST
spring.datasource.password=TEST
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: What is the error you get? If any?

Comment: When I try via postman I got 500 back. And if I debug the code it just get null objects back. While I put data inside the datbase

Comment: If you get a 500 there is a connection, if it wouldn't connect you would get a 404 as the application wouldn't start.

Comment: yes but I always returns null, so it doesn't get the data needed

Comment: I also did the test with a local db and no issue

Comment: The fact that you have `null` and no data indicates that there actually is a connection, because as stated else you would get a different exception. So the issue must be with your code or your data.